# How to remove some character from a string in Unix?

Tags: unix, shell-scripting, aix

I have two string like this
`a=[2018:09:11-18:37:06:376476]` 
`b=[2018:09:11-18:37:06:376446]`
I want two string like
`a= 20180911183706376476`
`b= 20180911183706376446`

Can Anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shell supports "//" substitutions in variables you can use

```
a=${a//[]:[-]/}
```

(notice that "-" should be last and "]" should be first in the `[...]` range expression.

If not, you can use something like this:

```
set_trim(){ local IFS=[:-]; v=$1; set -- $2; IFS=; eval "$v=$*"; }
set_trim a "$a"
set_trim b "$b"
```

or, with `sed` (less efficient since it has to start an external program):

```
a=`echo $a | sed 's/[]:[-]//g'`
```